# Trying to add validation using html5 Pattern

Tags: jquery, regex, html

- Trying to avoid space start and end of the string only allowed in between the string
- Minimum 2 character required
- special character and number validation

So I added a code like but not working for minimum two character validation

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    Full Name: 
   <input type="text" name="full_name"
          pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+ (\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$" 
          title="Enter your Full name( First name, Last name)">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: No special character and number validation - what do you mean by that? are those allowed or not?

Comment: Not allowed it is fixed but need to have minimum two character validation

Comment: ***Three** letter country code*? Why 2 char limit then?

Comment: Yeah... what do you mean by space only allowed between the string when it has to be 2 characters and space can't be first and last? That logically means that spaces are not allowed at all. And this code even without character limit doesnt accept "G B" ... maybe some examples?

Comment: And what country code has spaces inside to begin with?

Comment: Apologies for example!!! Forget that example just need with take an example of full name

Comment: First and last name or first, second, third, last name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `minlength="2"` (see [`minlength` support table](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-minlength)) to restrict the minimum length to 2 chars and remove the space between `+` and `(` as spaces are meaningful in regex patterns.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
    Full Name: 
   <input type="text" name="full_name" minlength="2"
          pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$" 
          title="Enter your Full name( First name, Last name)">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note that you may also remove `^` and `$` in the pattern and use

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*"
```

because HTML5 engine [will put the pattern in between `^(?:` and `)$`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-pattern-attribute), thus  ensuring an entire string match.

If browsers that do not support `minlength` should be supported, use a lookahead check at the start:

```
pattern="(?=.{2})[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*"
```

The `(?=.{2})` will require 2 chars immediately after start of the string is asserted (mind `pattern="(?=.{2})[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*"` will be translated into `/^(?:(?=.{2})[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)$/` regex, with or without `u` modifier depending on the browser).

Comment: @SaurabhGujarani Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer for pattern replace to this

```
^(?=.{2,}$)([a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)$
```

Comment: ok, good job... next time please be more specific when asking

Comment: Sure!!! I just added example my bad to explain it what actually we want next time I will take care
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @SaurabhGujarani You do not need to resort to lookaheads with HTML5. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983148/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pattern

`<form action="/action_page.php">
    Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2}" title="Two letter country code">
 <input type="submit">
</form>`

By default, it will not allow space at the start and end of the string and it has validation of minimum 2 characters and the third case will also work.

Comment: its not working with the space between character e.g Jai P showing error